WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED in BroadcastReceiver for api lower that 23
as Google doc says, you need to implement the following code, to be informed when WIFI scan operation is done:
(link of source)
val wifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val success = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false)
    if (success) {
      scanSuccess()
    } else {
      scanFailure()
    }
  }
}

but WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED requires api 23 and above, how to calculate success value in api lower than 23?
